# Is it possible to make homemade yogurt using chocolate milk?

Tags: chocolate, milk, yogurt

Making yogurt from a small quantity of live culture yogurt can be gussied up using cinnamon by adding the spice to the milk prior to boiling it.

Is it possible to make chocolate flavoured yogurt using boiled commercially made chocolate milk instead of boiled milk?

Comment: are you talking about commercially produced chocolate milk, or homemade chocolate milk?

Comment: I was thinking commercially made chocolate milk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't turn chocolate milk into yogurt.  Now, much commercial chocolate milk has carrageenan added as a stabilizer.  If you get issues with  carrageenan separating out, you can also use  Torani chocolate syrup (intended to flavor coffees) to add the flavor to normal milk.

Comment: carrageenan separating out? Why would you add carrageenan to your chocolate in the first place?

Comment: @rumtscho It's fairly common as a stabilizer in chocolate milk. The OP didn't put it in there.

Comment: @rumtscho: I have edited in an explanation of that

Comment: @BobMcGee I didn't even think of commercial chocolate milk :)

Comment: You could use unflavored milk and then add cocoa powder to the finished yogurt. I have done that with store bought greek yogurt and it tasted great even without added sugar. If you do want to add sugar you could use powdered sugar or a liquid sweetener like honey, agave nectar, or corn syrup.